# Warnings in `cond` testing with `fboundp`, why?

Tags: common-lisp

With following Common Lisp minimal example code (from a much more complex code base), I get warnings regarding line `((fboundp (car ',arg)) ,arg)` and I can't explain why or how to avoid them.

```
(defmacro cond-issue (&key (arg '(a b c)))
  (let ((arg-var (gensym "arg-var-")))
    `(let ((,arg-var (cond ((not (listp ',arg)) (list 'arg))
                           ((fboundp (car ',arg)) ,arg)
                           (t ',arg))))
       `(apply #'+ ,,arg-var))))

(cond-issue :arg (e f g))
```

CCL complains:

```
;Compiler warnings :
;   In an anonymous lambda form: Undefined function E
;   In an anonymous lambda form: Undeclared free variable F
;   In an anonymous lambda form: Undeclared free variable G
```

SBCL complains:

```
; in: cond-issue :arg
;     (E F G)
; 
; caught style-warning:
;   undefined function: common-lisp-user::e
; 
; caught warning:
;   undefined variable: common-lisp-user::f
; 
; caught warning:
;   undefined variable: common-lisp-user::g
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     e
;   Undefined variables:
;     f g
;   caught 2 WARNING conditions
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
```

CLISP does not complain.

<s>With SBCL I tried both: compiling and evaluating the code, with no difference regarding the warnings.</s>   [edit: I learned from the answers that I did that wrong]

This would be an (silly) example use case for the second `cond` form.

```
(cond-issue :arg (car '(e f g)))
;; ⇒ (apply #'+ e)
```

What is the explanation, why CCL and SBCL are complaining?
And how can I write the code to satisfy CCL and SBCL?

Comment: if you want to debug macros, then you also should look at the output of macro expansions of example code. is the expanded code generated as you intended it?

Comment: @RainerJoswig yes, the expansion looked like, what was intended. From the answers I learned, that I misunderstood `cond` when forms are compiled, and I made errors when switching sbcl into interpreted mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of this macro isn't really clear to me, but I think that the question about the nature of these warnings can be addressed. I have added some notes about a possible redesign at the end of the answer.

The reason that SBCL and CCL are complaining is that they are *compiling* code. The CLISP repl interprets code. If you open a fresh SBCL repl and put `eval` in interpreted mode the OP macro can be invoked without triggering warnings:

```
CL-USER> (setf *evaluator-mode* :interpret)
:INTERPRET
CL-USER> (defmacro cond-issue (&key (arg '(a b c)))
  (let ((arg-var (gensym "arg-var-")))
    `(let ((,arg-var (cond ((not (listp ',arg)) (list 'arg))
                           ((fboundp (car ',arg)) ,arg)
                           (t ',arg))))
       `(apply #'+ ,,arg-var))))
COND-ISSUE
CL-USER> (cond-issue :arg (e f g))
(APPLY #'+ (E F G))
```

After putting `eval` back in compiled mode the warnings appear:

```
CL-USER> (setf *evaluator-mode* :compile)
:COMPILE
CL-USER> (cond-issue :arg (e f g))
; in: COND-ISSUE :ARG
;     (E F G)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: COMMON-LISP-USER::E
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: COMMON-LISP-USER::F
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: COMMON-LISP-USER::G
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     E
;   Undefined variables:
;     F G
;   caught 2 WARNING conditions
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
(APPLY #'+ (E F G))
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(cond-issue :arg (e f g)))
(LET ((#:|arg-var-252|
       (COND ((NOT (LISTP '(E F G))) (LIST 'ARG))
             ((FBOUNDP (CAR '(E F G))) (E F G)) (T '(E F G)))))
  `(APPLY #'+ ,#:|arg-var-252|))
```

Looking at the macro expansion above it can be seen that one branch of the code to be compiled contains a function call with an undefined function and two undefined variables: `((FBOUNDP (CAR '(E F G))) (E F G))`. The compiler is complaining because it can't compile this code. I think that this is the behavior that you actually want, i.e., you should probably not attempt to circumvent compiler warnings for undefined functions and variables.

Consider some code that *should* compile:

```
CL-USER> (cond-issue :arg (list 1 2))
(APPLY #'+ (1 2))
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(cond-issue :arg (list 1 2)))
(LET ((#:|arg-var-258|
       (COND ((NOT (LISTP '(LIST 1 2))) (LIST 'ARG))
             ((FBOUNDP (CAR '(LIST 1 2))) (LIST 1 2)) (T '(LIST 1 2)))))
  `(APPLY #'+ ,#:|arg-var-258|))
```

Here the form `(LIST 1 2)` has replaced the previous `(E F G)`, and this presents no problem for the compiler. Note that the resulting form above is `(APPLY #'+ (1 2))`, and this is not legal lisp code. I think that the intention was to generate `(APPLY #'+ '(1 2))` instead. Further, the invocation `(cond-issue :arg 42)` yields `(APPLY #'+ (ARG))` where I suspect that `(APPLY #'+ '(42))` was desired. Here is a slightly modified version of `cond-issue` that fixes these problems:

```lisp
(defmacro cond-issue-fixed (&key (arg '(a b c)))
  (let ((arg-var (gensym "arg-var-")))
    `(let ((,arg-var (cond ((not (listp ',arg)) (list ',arg))
                           ((fboundp (car ',arg)) ,arg)
                           (t ',arg))))
       `(apply #'+ ',,arg-var))))
```

Again, I think that you should not try to circumvent these compiler warnings, but as an experiment, and in the spirit of patching together a half-baked solution, you could wrap `cond-issue` in a macro that checks the arguments first:

```lisp
(defmacro cond-issue-check (&key (arg '(a b c)))
  `(when (every (lambda (item)
                  (or (boundp item)
                      (fboundp item)))
                (remove-if-not #'symbolp ',arg))
     (cond-issue-fixed :arg ,arg)))
```

This solution has a couple of caveats: `boundp` and `fboundp` check for bindings in the global environment, but they cannot inspect local bindings (and I'm not sure that there is any simple way to do this). Also, the wrapper will reject macro invocations like `(cond-issue-check :arg 42)` with an error. The `cond-issue-check` wrapper could be augmented to better validate input, but the current definition should suffice to make the point. Now would be a good time to interrogate the purpose of the macro, whether it needs to be a macro at all, and to revisit the design.

```
CL-USER> (cond-issue-check :arg (e f g))
NIL
CL-USER> (cond-issue-check :arg (list 1 2))
(APPLY #'+ '(1 2))
CL-USER> (let ((a 1) (b 2))
           (cond-issue-check :arg (list a b)))
NIL
```

In the final example above the checking wrapper can't determine whether the local bindings for `a` and `b` are bound. The original, unwrapped `cond-issue` could be called when local bindings are needed, but this means that warnings may be triggered for unbound functions or variables.

In any case, the above fix will not stop all warnings for missing definitions. In general I wouldn't recommend trying to suppress these types of warnings, and I wouldn't recommend using `cond-issue-check`. It is probably best to let the compiler do its job.

### Redesigning the Macro

It seems that the OP goal is to take as input forms which describe other forms to which `#'+` can be applied, and from this to create forms which are not required to be valid in their current environment. If this is the case, here is an alternative design.

```lisp
(defmacro cond-something ((&rest args))
  `(if (and (symbolp ',(car `,args))
            (fboundp ',(car `,args)))
       `(apply #'+ ',,args)
       `(apply #'+ ',',args)))
```

Here if the first element of an input form is a symbol which is fbound, a form which applies `#'+` to the result of calling the input form is generated. Otherwise a form which applies `#'+` to *all* of the arguments is generated.

Some example invocations:

```
CL-USER> (cond-something (42))
(APPLY #'+ '(42))
CL-USER> (eval *)
42
CL-USER> (cond-something (list 1 2 3))
(APPLY #'+ '(1 2 3))
CL-USER> (eval *)
6
CL-USER> (cond-something (mapcar (lambda (x) (* 2 x)) '(1 2 3 4 5)))
(APPLY #'+ '(2 4 6 8 10))
CL-USER> (eval *)
30
CL-USER> (cond-something (e f g))
(APPLY #'+ '(E F G))
CL-USER> (eval *)
; Evaluation aborted on #<TYPE-ERROR expected-type: NUMBER datum: E>.
```

As previously mentioned, `fboundp` inspects global bindings, but it cannot tell whether lexical variables are bound to functions, i.e., those created with `flet` or `labels`. Here are examples showing the use of a global function for which `cond-something` generates the expected output, and the use of a local function for which `cond-something` would not generate the code one might naively expect:

```
CL-USER> (defun g (x y) (list (* x y)))
G
CL-USER> (cond-something (g 2 3))
(APPLY #'+ '(6))
CL-USER> (flet ((f (x y) (list (* x y))))
           (cond-something (f 2 3)))
(APPLY #'+ '(F 2 3))
```

Comment: Great answer! The un-guessable purpose of my given example, was due to my rewriting the problematic macro as an example for SO. I'm going the redesign route to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

addition:

**CLISP complains, too:**

```
CL-USER> (lisp-implementation-type)
"CLISP"

CL-USER> (defmacro cond-issue (&key (arg '(a b c)))
           (let ((arg-var (gensym "arg-var-")))
             `(let ((,arg-var (cond ((not (listp ',arg)) (list 'arg))
                                    ((fboundp (car ',arg)) ,arg)
                                    (t ',arg))))
                `(apply #'+ ,,arg-var))))
COND-ISSUE
CL-USER> (defun test () (cond-issue :arg (e f g)))
TEST
```

Now let's compile the function `TEST:

```
CL-USER> (compile 'test)
WARNING: in TEST : Function E is not defined
WARNING: in TEST : F is neither declared nor bound,
         it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.
WARNING: in TEST : G is neither declared nor bound,
         it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.
TEST
3
3
```

You then need to look at the macroexpansion:

```
CL-USER> (pprint (macroexpand '(cond-issue :arg (e f g))))

(LET
 ((#:|arg-var-16322|
   (COND ((NOT (LISTP '(E F G))) (LIST 'ARG))
    ((FBOUNDP (CAR '(E F G))) (E F G)) (T '(E F G)))))
 (LIST 'APPLY '#'+ #:|arg-var-16322|))
; No value
```

Then see the answer by *ad absurdum*...